# What the space in UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have UITextField for login and password in authorisation window 
the Password textField has securetyTextEntry = YES; After I press the "Show" button it's change to NO and user can see his password. 
But when i press the button and it changed, in UITextField i SEE the space(image 2) but it's just  visual, there are not any space or character. Help pleas

First image:

[image: First image]

Second image:

[image: Second image]

Comment: File a bug report. The insertion point is located where it would have been if we had six bullets before it, and it should not be. Meanwhile, I think you can fix this just by changing the selection.

Comment: Totally a caret bug on iOS. Meanwhile you could probably fix it by forcing text-field to relayout whether via setNeedsLayout or better by re-assigning the right view.